# Add query string url in Go

Tags: url, go

I need to send http request to `https://some-domain.com/getsomething/?id=myID` 
I have url and need to add to it a query parameter. Here is my Go code

```
baseUrl := "https://some-domain.com"
relativeUrl := "/getsomething/"
url, _ := url.Parse(baseUrl)
url.Path = path.Join(url.Path, relativeUrl)

// add parameter to query string
queryString := url.Query()
queryString.Set("id", "1")
// add query to url
url.RawQuery = queryString.Encode()
// print it 
fmt.Println(url.String())
```

In output I see this url: `https://some-domain.com/getsomething?id=1`

And this one is required: `https://some-domain.com/getsomething/?id=1`

You can see that there is no `/` character before `?`.

Do you know how to fix it without manual string manipulations?

https://play.golang.org/p/HsiTzHcvlQ

Comment: Everything is ok with this code, for me the output is `https://some-domain.com/getsomething/?id=1`. I have edited your code, because the [Set](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Set) function takes a string as a value.

Comment: I tried your program, and the output is as you require (`https://some-domain.com/getsomething/?id=1`). on Playground -  https://play.golang.org/p/M87JQqFb45

Comment: I'm sorry, I made my code in this question more simple. Updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ResolveReference](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.ResolveReference).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    relativeUrl := "/getsomething/"
    u, err := url.Parse(relativeUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    queryString := u.Query()
    queryString.Set("id", "1")
    u.RawQuery = queryString.Encode()

    baseUrl := "https://some-domain.com"
    base, err := url.Parse(baseUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(u))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BIU29R_XBM

Comment: Yop, my bad. Updated.